# vim: Having trouble rebinding Escape to jj

Tags: vim

All my other keybindings are working correctly, but I can't bind `jj` to escape for some reason.  Mashing `jk` or `kj` doesn't work either.  Here is my entire .vimrc:

```
    "Maps for jj to act as Esc
inoremap jk <Esc>
inoremap kj <Esc>
"inoremap jj <Esc>
ino jj <Esc>
cno jj <C-c>

set number
set nocompatible 
set paste

    "fix cygwin backspace problem
set backspace=indent,eol,start
fixdel

set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
    "use spaces instead of \t
"set expandtab 
set nowrap

syntax on
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=lightgreen
autocmd Syntax * syn match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
    "remove trailing whitespace
    "http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces#Automatically_removing_all_trailing_whitespace
"autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.c :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.cpp :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.c++ :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.h :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.java :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.php :%s/\s\+$//e

autocmd BufWritePre *.pl :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre *.py :%s/\s\+$//e
"autocmd FileType c,cpp,c++,java,php,pl,py autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :call setline(1,map(getline(1,"$"),'substitute(v:val,

    "search options
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set showmatch

nmap <space> zz
nmap n nzz
nmap N Nzz

    "set arrow keys to move between buffer / tabs
inoremap <Up> :bprev<CR>
inoremap <Down> :bnext<CR>
inoremap <Left> :tabprev<CR>
inoremap <Right> :tabnext<CR>
noremap <Up> :bprev<CR>
noremap <Down> :bnext<CR>
noremap <Left> :tabprev<CR>
noremap <Right> :tabnext<CR>

set vb t_vb=
set guioptions-=T

"set foldmethod=indent
set showtabline=2

"au BufWinLeave * mkview
"au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

For the record, timeoutlen is set to the default of 1000 ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the answer researching an unrelated .vimrc question.  Using `set paste` disables insert abbreviations, even if it never actually every worked for me in .vimrc.

Comment: "set paste" works for me; I wonder if you are expecting some other behavior from it.  It just turns off everything "smart" that would interfere with a paste (key macros, autoindent, etc.).  Turn it on before pasting, off afterward.

Comment: It works when I use `set paste` in command mode, but not in the .vimrc.  When I post from X the formatting is still messed up.

There are side effects from using `set paste`, so I'm trying to use `"+p` or `"*p` instead.

Comment: Well, yes; you're not supposed to leave it on, is my point.  So I'm not surprised that sticking it in `~/.vimrc` is ignored.

Comment: @geekosaur It should not be ignored, something is interfering with `set paste`. You could test it with `vim -u <(echo "set rtp= paste")`: it works fine.

Comment: @William Ting You should try to setup mouse in terminal if terminal supports it. Using `set mousemode=extend mouse=hide ttymouse=xterm2` works for me with `urxvt+dtach`. It won't work in ssh though. A bunch of mappings like these: `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> "*p|
vnoremap <MiddleMouse> d"*p|
xnoremap <MiddleMouse> <C-g>d"*p|
lnoremap <MiddleMouse> <C-r><C-r>*|
inoremap <MiddleMouse> <C-r><C-r>*|
onoremap <MiddleMouse> <Nop>` will force vim not to move cursor on middle mouse.

Comment: Thanks but I use ssh in terminal exclusively.  I even ssh into localhost to run screen so workflow is uninterrupted when jumping onto another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You want `inoremap jj <Esc>`, which you seem to have commented. Uncomment it and comment/delete the other mappings for `jj`. Does that work?